# select checkbox the statement or text will appear in html

Tags: html, if-statement, checkbox

why my coding doesn't work? I want it like this; if select checkbox the statement or text will appear based on if else or swith. can u fix my coding? whats wrong with my coding? Here's my code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ShowHideDiv(Fish) {
    var subAnimal = document.getElementById("subFish");
    subFish.style.display = Fish.checked ? "block" : "none";
    console.log(Fish.value)
    console.log("Text Inside LABEL:" + Fish.parentNode.textContent)
  }
</script>

<label for="Fish">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Fish" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this)" value="Fish"/> Fish 
</label>

<div id="subFish" style="display: none">

  <label> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="subFish1" /> Tank 
</label>

  <label> 
    <p id="subFishs1" ></p> 
</label>

  <label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="subFish2" /> Fishing 
</label>

  <label> 
    <p id="subFishs2" ></p> 
</label>

  <script>
    function ShowHideDiv2(this) {

      var a = document.getElementById("subAnimal1").checked;
      var b = document.getElementById("subAnimal2").checked;

      if (a && b) {
        document.getElementById("subAnimal1").addEventListener("click", function() {
              document.getElementById("subAnimals1").innerHTML = "Bad";
            } else if (a && !b) {
              document.getElementById("subAnimal2").addEventListener("click", function() {
                  document.getElementById("subAnimals2").innerHTML = "Cute";
                } else {
                  alert("Under Development!");
                }
              }
  </script>
```

Comment: when I run the snippet there's an error:  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 43,
  "colno": 27    .also Notice function ShowHideDiv2 is not used

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of errors in your code. You should use jquery instead using core javascript. Here is the example to show hide div using jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Elements Using Checkboxes</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #228B22; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
    label{ margin-right: 15px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        $("." + inputValue).toggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="red"> red</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="green"> green</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="blue"> blue</label>
    </div>
    <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
</body>
</html>
```